# How to send Base64 encode image servlet?

Tags: image, servlets, base64

For my project, I had created a "*question.jsp*" & in that I had used fileupload control to upload image to Servlet. It works perfectly fine for New Entry but when I retrieve the data for update, I succeeded to show image somehow( I had used JSON & images are sent as Base64 string). Image displayed perfectly as background of DIV but now If I submit this data to Servlet it wont save that image because the image is not a part of Form Data. 
    Now my question is that, Is it possible to assign Base64 encode image to fileupload control? Or how I can send that Base64 encode images back to servlet? (In current scenario, it goes null because fileupload control is send null)
   Please help me to provide proper solution for this.

Thanks in Advance
Anand...